# Maybe did wrong trying to shut down my 2011.12 Pi

Tags: shutdown

I was trying to shut down my 2011.12 raspberry pie. I am brand new to it and probably don’t have a clue what I’m doing. I saw a place online that said hit Ctrl X followed by y at the prompt. When I hit control X on my desktop icons disappeared!? Did I mess up?

Additional info has been requested, such as OS and GUI I’m using. I do not know how to get that info. There are no menu or command bars on top of desktop view. I’m at a loss on how to provide more details or clarity. And, I’m having sone difficulty navigating around in this site to view answers or advice.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the power and then power up again?

Comment: Yes. I unplugged it and plugged it back in and the icons are back and all seems like it was.

Comment: Sorry Millways, stupid auto word changed what I typed and I didn’t catch it. I meant Raspberry Pi of course.

Comment: @Ron what is preventing you from correcting it?

Comment: If you seriously want help you need to provide some information. Start with `lsb_release -irdc` and `uname -a` rather than meaningless "2011.12 raspberry pi"

Comment: I want to provide the needed info I just don’t know how to get it. Is the lsb… something I type into terminal? Tried and it said command not found

Comment: I did manage safe shutdown using sudo shutdown now recommended by one responder. The GUI has no shutdown option I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a GUI there should be a shutdown option off one of the main menus.

If you are using a terminal use

`sudo shutdown`

or if you want to reboot

`sudo reboot`

Comment: I’m using a gui but there does not seem to be any main menus. No raspberry icon either.

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain which GUI you are using.

Comment: How do I tell which GUI I have? This is my first experience with raspberry pi.